# Как выбрать брата родителя jquery

Tags: jquery

Подскажите пожалуста как выбрать брата родителя вот код

html

```
 <div class="gallery">
     <div class="big"></div>
      <div class="small">
       <a href="#">click</a>
      </div>
     </div>
    <div class="gallery">
     <div class="big"></div>
      <div class="small">
       <a href="#">click</a>
      </div>
     </div>
```

jqury
 я пытаюсь выбрать конкретный div big который брат родителя small ссылки click вот так

```
$(this).parent('.small').siblings('.big img')
```

понимаю что туплю поскольку только учусь jquery  помогите пожалуста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понимаю, вам надо не "брата родителя" выбрать, а изображение внутри того самого "брата родителя". Тогда можно или так:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('.small')
        .siblings('.big')
        .find('img')
        .css('border','1px solid #F00');
});
```

или же таким образом:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.gallery')
        .find('.big img')
        .css('border','1px solid #F00');
});
```

Работу [смотрите тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/LKwCt/)

Comment: Спасибо большое а если ещё чуть услажнить не просто рисунок а ещё ссылку а потом рисунок это надо вот так 
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('.small')
        .siblings('.big')

        .find('img')

Comment: Вы структурку html этого усложненного примера покажите. Потому, как если вам нужна ссылка, по которой кликали, то она и есть в $(this)

Comment: Спасибо я разобрался вы очень помогли :)